# Having a shadow on my sidebar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a right sidebar on my page and I would like to have a shadow on the left side of this sidebar. A very light shadow like the one showed on the Google Maps left sidebar ( http://maps.google.be). Is it possible?

Here is a jsFiddle to have an idea: http://jsfiddle.net/yhfXX/3/

Normally the sidebar should take the full height but this jsFiddle is just an example.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use the `box-shadow` css rule to create a drop shadow.

```
#sidebar {
  -moz-box-shadow:    -3px 0 5px 0 #555;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 0 5px 0 #555;
  box-shadow:         -3px 0 5px 0 #555;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/c2Fzj/)**

The use is:

1. **The horizontal offset** of the shadow, positive means the shadow will be on the right of the box, a negative offset will put the shadow on the left of the box.
2. **The vertical offset** of the shadow, a negative one means the box-shadow will be above the box, a positive one means the shadow will be below the box.
3. **The blur radius (optional)**, if set to 0 the shadow will be sharp, the higher the number, the more blurred it will be.
4. **The spread radius (optional)**, positive values increase the size of the shadow, negative values decrease the size. Default is 0 (the shadow is same size as blur).
5. **Color**

[Box-shadow support table](http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow)

Comment: And, you can use [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/) if you want to support Internet Exploder.

Answer (score 0):

that's the css3 inset shadow:

```
.shadow {
   -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;
}
```

adjust the 10px to your need

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS for that, like so:

```
text-shadow: 0px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

experiment with it to find the best setup for you =)

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported from w3c:

```
.shadow {
   **-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;**
   **-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;**
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;
}
```